# How to keep always logged in development environment

Tags: login, wp-login-form, single-sign-on

I have a little non-standard WP dev environment, I use one WP core for all my projects and switch each project in core's wp-config.php just changing the `$project` variable (e.g. proj1, proj2, example...). Projects and core are separated and each project has its own DB, wp-content folder, wp-config-dev.php (DB credentials and table prefix), and wp-config.php (usual wp-config that I deploy on the server).

```php
//core's wp-config.php
<?php
$project = 'example';
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', 'C:/dev/projects/'.$project.'/wp/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://projects.folder/'.$project.'/wp/wp-content' );
include('C:/dev/projects/'.$project.'/wp/wp-config-dev.php');
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
}
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );
// custom functions
include('custom.php');
```

All my projects on the development environment have the same user and password (e.g. foo and bar) and I change them when I export DB when my project is ready to production, so my goal to switch each project just with changing `$project` and not login in every time cuz it is really annoying.

When i switch beetwen projects i have always to log in again into switched project. In included `custom.php` file i have `wp_signon()` function that was worked on WP 4+ but since WP 5.0 it is stopped working. Earlier that approach automatically logged in each project and i even can't log out cuz it keep me logged on page reload :)

```php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if (!user_can( $current_user, 'administrator' )) {
    //without if(){} i have same behaviour
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = 'foo';
    $creds['user_password'] = 'bar';
    $creds['remember'] = false;
    wp_signon( $creds, false );
}
```

Now after the switch, I need to update the page again to the admin bar appear and when I go to the console it redirects me to wp-login.php where is user input had filled and the password input are empty.

[image]

So how to make it always automatically logged in when I change the project and make that each session has no expiration time?

**Note.** I need to make it work only in the custom.php file that I include to core's wp-config, I don't need to make it in each project instance that I deploy on the server.

---

**Update**. Now autologin works fine, the problem was in second parameter of the `wp_signon()` function, it should be true if you use HTTPS on your site.

```php
//custom.php

echo "is_user_logged_in() — ";
var_dump(is_user_logged_in());

//this condition not working after switch project, have to reload page
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = 'foo';
    $creds['user_password'] = 'bar';
    $creds['remember'] = false;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, true ); //set second parameter to true to enable secure cookies

    add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year' );
    function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $expirein ) {
        return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
    }
}
```

It always keep me logged in for current project and I haven't problem with redirection to wp-login page but when i switch to another project I still need to reload page to login and for the admin bar to appear.

*In drop down menu i switch project with changing `$project` var in core's config*
[image]

How to login immediately and without reloads after changing `$project`? Is there a problem with that engine got another DB and wp-content folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my solution, I just need make an additional redirect to make `wp_signon()` work after I switch project.

```php
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = 'foo';
    $creds['user_password'] = 'bar';
    $creds['remember'] = false;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, true ); 

    add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year' );
    function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $expirein ) {
        return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
    }

    //add redirection
    header("Location: "."https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one milder suggestion to try out, assuming different cookie domains, if you're using WordPress 5.5+

For your *development* installs, set the *getenv* environment variable `WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE` or define:

```
define( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'development' );
```

within the corresponding `wp-config-development.php` or the name you use for it.

Then extend the [authentication cookie expiration period](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auth_cookie_expiration/) for the *development* installs with e.g.

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', function( $ttl, $user_id, $remember ) {

    // Adjust to your working environment needs.
    $my_working_types = [ 'development' ];
    $my_working_ttl   = YEAR_IN_SECONDS;

    return in_array( wp_get_environment_type(), $my_working_types, true ) 
        ? $my_working_ttl 
        : $ttl;

}, PHP_INT_MAX - 1, 3 );
```

So you would have to login once to start with, **checking** the "Remember me" on the login screen, else we get the *session* expiration.

There are [four](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/load.php?rev=48662#L151) supported environment types of `wp_get_environment_type()` supported:

- *local*
- *development*
- *staging*
- *production* (default)

See the [dev notes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/24/new-wp_get_environment_type-function-in-wordpress-5-5/) for the back story.

ps: The setup of using the same domain, with multiple sites in sub-directories, sharing the same WordPress install, reminds me of [WordPress multisite](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am unsure about implementation environments with 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', the main problem (now) that after switch I have to reload page to login in and for admin bar appear. I suppose it is a great point about different cookie domains (cuz I switch between different DBs even there is same log-pass), but honestly I am not so know how cookies works under the hood.

Comment: I also had updated the question with problem demonstration

Comment: Looks like you're using the same domain for all. Sounds like you're building your own **sub-directory multisite**. Maybe you should look into WP multisite? Maybe you can add your own redirection to homepage to avoid manual reloading, but be careful when deploying with auto-login code and for storing passwords in php files.

Comment: This looks great! But, weirdly, if I fully close my browser and reopen it, I still have to login again... It only remembers me between browser sessions if I check 'Remember Me' on the login screen. I looked into `wp_set_auth_cookie` in pluggable.php and this seems to cause the different behavior if `$remember` is `false`: `$expire = 0;`

Comment: Thanks @rassoh, I should have mentioned that this should be used with "Remember me" checked, else we get the session expire.